# How to apply android system equalizer settings on MediaPlayer object?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, equalizer

I'm a newbie in programming and android development.
So I have a problem: all music players, such as Apple Music, Sony's Music app and other ones use system audio effects (from settings app), but my app doesn't. I don't know how to apply system audio output settings and effects on my app.
Here is my class which uses Media Player:

```
public class MPlayer {

private static String File = null;
private static boolean isNew = false;
private static MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
private static Equalizer mEqualizer;


public static void setFile2Play(String file){
    if(!file.equals(File)){
        File = file;
        isNew = true;
        try {
            if(mPlayer != null){
                mPlayer.release();
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            }
            mPlayer.setDataSource(file);
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.prepare();
            mEqualizer = new Equalizer(1,mPlayer.getAudioSessionId());
            mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);


        }catch (IOException e){}



    }
    else isNew = false;

}

public static void play(){
    if(isNew) {
        mPlayer.start();

    }
}
public static boolean isPlaying() {return mPlayer.isPlaying();}
public static void seekTo(int i){mPlayer.seekTo(i);}
public static int getCurrentPosition(){return mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();}
public static int getDuration(){return mPlayer.getDuration();}
public static void pause(){mPlayer.pause();}
public static void stop(){mPlayer.stop();}
```

}